# How to propagate the new variable type and redefine all the functions that are using it with the new type in IDA?

Tags: ida, idapython, idapro-sdk

Lets say there is a variable x in f1, and f1 calls f2 with the variable x

I want ida to automatically redefine the definition of any function like f2, that is using the variable that i just changed its type. how can i do this? because right if x is getting passed to 100 functions, i need to manually redefine EVERY SINGLE one!